# Scope of temporary table in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I am trying to understand the scope of temporary table in Greenplum.

I run the below statement from one session.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sample_table as select '1' as id, 'test' as val;
```

And its surprising to me that I am able to execute the below statements from a different session.

```
select * from sample_table;
drop table sample_table;
```

Previously I have been using MySQL and this would not work there since temporary table are specific to the session they are created in. However in Greenplum, I am able to access a temporary table created in one session from a different session.

Can anyone explain this behaviour.
Is this greenplum specific or postgres behaves like this in general.

Thank you.

Comment: This will definitely not work in PostgreSQL, you have to use the same database connection to see the temp table and it's data. I have no idea about Greenplum

Answer (score 2):

Temp tables in Greenplum use shared buffers (and not local buffers as upstream PostgreSQL). It's designed this way in Greenplum because Greenplum can create many processes for a session (called slices) to execute the query. And each of these processes belonging to the same session should have access to the temp table data. Hence, temp tables are logically accessible from other sessions as well as they are pretty much similar to regular tables.

Though important thing to note is, the life-cycle of temp table is still bonded by the session it's created in similar to PostgreSQL. Hence, when the session which created the table exits the temp table will be deleted along with it.